# Docdokuplm install pom.xml

Tags: xml, installation

I'm trying to manage to set up everything on a VM to evaluate your product but i'm stuck with the install.

When I try to run mvn install on root folder of  docdokuplm i've got error that say eplmp/pom.xml does not exist. I can confirm that this is the case.

I can't send code result because linux vm server don't know how to copy paste result between guest and host.

Note that I'm not an expert in programming so please be specific in question/answers.

Comment: I don't think SO is right place for this question.

Comment: I try to use tag docdokuplm but it is not available. Where would be the right place ?

Comment: I think https://superuser.com/